# Hosting web server via FTTH (Fibre To The Home) or datacenter

Tags: datacenter, isp, colocation, fiber, hosting

I'm a .Net programmer that currently using web hosting provider to host my web applications.

In my place, currently there is offer of **20 Mbps FTTH** (Fibre To The Home) internet line by an ISP. This ISP controls nearly 80% of the nationwide telephony services and is the big player of broadband industry in my country.

And I'm so tempted to self host my web applications using that 20 Mbps FTTH line. The cost of server co-location with **1 Mbps line at data center** in my place is roughly just the same with 20 Mbps line. So strange, but it is true situation in my place.

**20 Mbps FTTH line** vs **1 Mbps data center line**, which is better based on speed and reliability?

Answer (score 3):

Your constraint seems to be budget. Just think about this (in no particular order):

- How much does a downtime cost (per minute)?
- When was the last power outage?
- Do you have a pet or kids that could do stupid stuff?
- When was the last outage from you ISP?
- How much will the power cost you for a server?
- Is your partner capable of leaving that stuff alone

> **You**: Did you do something with the server?
>   **Partner**: No, why?
>   **You**: Well we have an outage and are loosing money...
>   **Partner**: But I just moved it from the living room to the bedroom, I even plugged all the cables in again!?
>   **You**: **sigh**

- Have you considered going to some VPS Hoster, I heard rumors those stuff is available for under EUR 10,- for Windows (it definitely is for Linux so it can't be that far off)

Comment: I just tempted with the 20 Mbps figure! But also wonder why 1 Mbps at data center so pricey. For your info, 20 Mbps FTTH line costs USD 280 per month in my place.

Comment: Making decision by only relying on a single datapoint is almost always going to hurt soon after the decision. That is why I deliberately didn't mention that. All the other stuff is something you'll have to figure out. You might even end up just paying some professional admin (since you say *I'm a programmer*) if you decide it's the most cost effective way. There tends to be stuff programmers don't think about and stuff admins don't think about :)

Comment: Yup, I really a newbie in server (web and db) admin.

Answer (score 3):

It comes down to the business requirements vs. expectations. Is a detailed SLA (Service Level Agreement) part of the expectations? As part of the SLA, is advance notices of maintenance activities/events a requirement and/or expectation?

In most case advance notifications do not exist with a lot of residential/small business ISP services and acknowledgement of any event typically requires the subscriber in taking initial action. Those factors may need be considered as to how acceptable that may or may not be against your business requirements and expectations.

Comment: The ISP says the 20 Mbps FTTH speed based on BEST EFFORT. But the data center says guaranteed 1 Mbps.

Comment: That also another different point - continuous service vs. stated best effort maximum. Is there at least an identified "not to drop below" minimum? If so, that should also be factored against your business requirements and expectations as well.

Comment: The ISP didn't mention the minimum speed.

Comment: You might inquire about that as well, if you are leaning towards that direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think you seriously need to consider **all** aspects of hosting. Unless this is for hobby purposes, your datacenter is probably the better choice. They provide redundant and more reliable connectivity, cooling, reserve power, etc.

Professional hosting is not done from a FTTH line. I have a 100/100 Mbit FTTH line at home and would not consider it for hosting my SMB company's webservers.

Comment: Yes, there is 1 Gbps offer from that datacenter too

Comment: That's not what I mean. 100Mbit bandwidth is fine. It's the stability, redundancy and other aspects of a datacenter that you should look for.